# swift showing a hidden container view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a container view like this:

[image]

The main is called ConfigViewContainer and the child is called ConfigDistrictViewController which has a UIPicker on it.
If I dont set in the storyboard ConfigDistrictViewController as hidden then it shows.

[image]

Now I want to show it via code when i do a touchdown event in the ConfigViewController textfield control.

```
var configDistrictViewController: ConfigDistrictViewController?
var uiView : UIView?

@IBAction func selectDistrictTouchDown(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ConfigDistrictSelectionSegue", sender: self)

}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "ConfigDistrictViewController")
    {
        configDistrictViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ConfigDistrictViewController

        configDistrictViewController?.showContainer()

        // Also tried the following      
        uiView = configDistrictViewController?.view
        uiView?.hidden = false


    }
}
```

Here is the code in the ConfigDistrictViewController:

```
func showContainer()
{
    println("showContainer")
    self.view.hidden = true
}
```

but all i get is error like this:

[image]

The failure happens here:

```
        configDistrictViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ConfigDistrictViewController
```

so I'm thinking I may be using:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ConfigDistrictSelectionSegue", sender: self)
```

incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `ConfigViewContainer` is instantiated, its child, `ConfigDistrictViewController` is also, so that segue has already been executed. Instead of hiding the view controller, you can prevent the segue from being executed (when `ConfigViewContainer` is instantiated) by implementing `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:`. and returning false. That method is not called when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` in code, so you should be able to do something like this,

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Embed"]) { // The embed segue in IB was given this identifier. This method is not called when calling performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: in code (as in the button method below)
        return NO;
    }else{
        return  YES;
    }
}


- (IBAction)showEmbed:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Embed" sender:self];
}
```

I took this code from a previous project. If you need me to translate it to Swift, I can.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.  Makes sense now.  I was able to transform it to swift.